# Minimum wage divided by cost of living?

Tags: microeconomics

Is there some commonly known indicator that is defined as:  Minimum wage divided by cost of living? I mean, I could call it that way, but perhaps people already have this indicator with a certain specific name or they have a better one for the purpose I'm looking for.

Comment: You did not reveal your purpose...

Comment: Economists do not believe that there is something called "the cost of living". To economists, this is a term that is impossible to define because it varies wildly depending on social and cultural norms and one's personal habits. What a citizen of a developed country considers "the cost of living" is very different from what a citizen of a developing country considers "the cost of living". And hence, it is unlikely that economists have come up with the indicator you are looking for.

Comment: @KennyLJ Basically anything suffers from the problem you mentioned.

Comment: No that is not true. For example, if you asked about the minimum wage in various countries, an answer would be possible. Or if you asked about the minimum cost of bare subsistence, economists have come up with estimates. But "cost of living" is an ill-defined term.

Comment: @KennyLJ How can you be sure that everyone in the country respects the minimum wage law uniformly? An economy can bypass that via informality. (Happens A LOT in my country). You can only believe that the information given by someone (eg: government) is true.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Kaitz-Index, which relates the minimum wage to the average hourly wage, thus facilitating cross-country comparisons on the minimum wage level. The OECD has compiled it [here](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIN2AVE). There you'll also find other metrics comparing minimum wage levels across countries.

Comment: I'm looking for something that allows me to know "how easy" it is to live in a country with a given minimum wage.

Comment: That's the purpose of the Kaitz-Index, although it's far from perfect. However, mind within-country differences: The French minimum wage will earn a different living standard in Paris compared to the Picardie.

Comment: If you have the time, it would be useful to add some references for this index.